# Directive with <select ng-options> and indirection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have several multi-selects on a page, each with a bit of logic that fills that multi-select from the server, and I want to wrap each one up into a Directive.

Before trying to wrap these into Directives, I built each as such:

**index.html**

```
<select name="groups" ng-model="inputs.groups" ng-change="groupsChanged()" ng-options="g for g in allgroups" multiple></select>
```

**controllers.js**

In the first pass, I do my $http calls from here. Yes, I know, not best practices, but I wanted to prove that this works to myself first.

```
  $scope.loadSelect = function(_url) {
    $http({
      url: _url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: $scope.inputs,
      model: 'all' + _url
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope[config.model] = data;
    });
  };

  // Fill groups
  $scope.loadSelect('groups');

  // When groups change, reload other select fields that depend on groups
  $scope.groupsChanged = function() {
    $scope.loadSelect('categories');
    $scope.loadSelect('actions');
  }
```

Now I want to migrate this to a Directive. I see two major challenges:
1.) How do I encapsulate the entire set of options (e.g. what is now the "allgroups" model) into the Directive?
2.) Based on initial experiments, I tried to physically build the `<select/>` into the template, but realized that I have to manipulate the DOM to physically replace name, ng-model, and ng-options. That lead me to the compile attribute, but a.) that feels wrong and b.) setting `<select ng-options="x for x in allgroups" />` doesn't actually repeat after it's been inserted into the DOM.  Using compile doesn't feel right; what's the right way to approach this?

Here is my first attempt at the Directive looks like this. It doesn't really work, and I think I'm going about it incorrectly:

**index.html**

```
<dimension ng-model="inputs.users" alloptions-model="allusers">Users</dimension>
```

**directives.js**

```
directive('dimension', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      alloptionsModel: '='
    },
    template:
        '<div>' + 
          '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
          '<fieldset>' +
              '<div class="form-group">' +
                '<select ng-model="{{ngModel}}" ng-options="x for x in {{alloptionsModel}}" multiple class="form-control"></select>' +
              '</div>' +
           '</fieldset>' +
        '</div>',

    replace: true,
    transclude: true
  };
});
```

Clearly I haven't even gotten to the server load part yet, but I plan to roll that into a controller in the Directive, with the actual $http call in a service.

I feel like I'm moving down the wrong track. If you have suggestions on how to realign, please help!

Comment: heres a great short video by Lukas Ruebbelke might help you out http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your directive is that you can't use mustache binding in `ngModel` and `ngOptions` directive because they are evaluated directly. You can directly bind to the scoped property (ngModel and alloptionsModel):

```
directive('dimension', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      alloptionsModel: '='
    },
    template:
        '<div>' + 
          '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
          '<fieldset>' +
              '<div class="form-group">' +
                '<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="x for x in alloptionsModel" multiple class="form-control"></select>' +
              '</div>' +
           '</fieldset>' +
        '</div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true
  };
});
```

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JQKVI0BKQAXnzBswTXd7) for a working example.

**Edit**
As for the compile route, there is nothing wrong with it. It is useful when you need to dynamically create a template which will clearly be your case when you will get to the `select`'s item template.

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
  var select = tElement.find('select'),
      value = tAttrs.value ? 'x.' + tAttrs.value : 'x',
      label = tAttrs.label ? 'x.' + tAttrs.label : 'x',
      ngOptions = value + ' as ' + label + ' for x in alloptionsModel';

      select.attr('ng-options', ngOptions);
}

// In the HTML file
<dimension ng-model="inputs.users" 
           alloptions-model="allusers"
           label="name">
  Users
</dimension>
```

I've updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JQKVI0BKQAXnzBswTXd7) with the compile function.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks. I'm trying to avoid using compile, per a comment I read somewhere (and can't find now) indicating that compile shouldn't be used often.  Any thoughts on how to bring the alloptionsModel entirely within the directive, so that that doesn't need to be visible outside the scope of the directive?