# Select directive not working right in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I have a simple directive to render `<select>` elements on my page that looks like this:

```
.directive('selectpicker', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        template: '<select><option ng-repeat="opt in options" value="{{opt.id}}">{{opt.descr}}</option></select>',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var $el = $(element);
            $el.on('change', function (ee, aa) {
                ngModel.$setViewValue($el.val());
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
```

Which is working fine. Values are binded to model variables so every select should be preselected when page displays. This is not working for me in Firefox, where nothing is selected on page but when I submit the data, values are set as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: use `ngOptions` in select instead of ng-repeat

Comment: Now I get error and the page is broken - "Controller 'select', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273632/directive-with-select-ng-options-and-indirection

Comment: Yes, this was the solution, thanks for pointing out!